# access artifactory running on docker container

Tags: docker, networking, virtualbox

My setup is :
On Windows 7 I installed Oracle Virtual Box.
On Virtual Box I'm running Ubuntu 16.
In Ubuntu, I'm running Docker Container, ip: 172.17.0.2
In docker container, I'm running Jfrog Artifactory which uses port 8081.

My question is:
From Windows how can I access my Jfrog Artifactory service?
( Using ip: 172.17.0.2 from windows, it's not accessible )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the IP of your Ubuntu VM. (Maybe something like 192.168.xx.xx) and visit that IP on port 8081: 192.168.xx.xx:8081.

```
$ docker run --name artifactory -d -p 8081:8081 docker.bintray.io/jfrog/artifactory-oss:latest
```

This will start a container in your Ubuntu VM and map port 8081 of the container on 8081 of your VM.

Comment: Yes, it's working. But if you don't apply -p 8081:8081 then don't.

Comment: @kunal indeed. If you don't specify it, it will not map the container port on the port of your host. So visiting the container-ip:port will only work from inside the Ubuntu and not from the outside. If you specify it it will map the container port on the port of the host and you can visit it too with host-ip:port